# How to get windows look on ubuntu?

Tags: windows, window

I like the functions of ubuntu. but I prefer the windows look.

Is there some ubuntu modification that looks like windows?

Ubuntu looks too cartoonish and unprofessional.

Windows ist more German-like. streight lines, sharp and thin cursors and fonts etc.

Including mouse cursors, fonts and window look?

I am currently using 13.04 version of Ubuntu.

It could be the old fashioned look:
[image]

Or aero:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it (Windows 7 Aero style):
http://www.howtogeek.com/55985/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7/
There's a short tutorial with images and installation instructions on the website I linked. If you aren't happy with the theme, the site also tells you how to uninstall.

Here's another tutorial. It's similar to the one above but longer and more detailed:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html

Comment: looks nice, except the buttons that looks horrible. I will probably try it. Are the mouse cursors windows like?

Comment: I'm not sure but they're quite close. By the way, here's another tutorial: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2028896/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-windows-7.html

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I'd show a bit more, and explain what's on the link. Nice answer, though, you beat me to it ;)

Comment: The top link is designed for Ubuntu 10.04, and does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Kubuntu, and customize it. There are themes for gtk, but unity is very . . . unity. KDE has a more traditional layout. If you use it, i'd use the aero mouse theme and vistar7 or something. If you go to the desktop settings, go to e.g. pointer -> get new themes, and then search for anything containing 'vista' or 'seven', I once made KDE look just like Win7, I think I found a windows 7 transformation pack or something.

Or, if you want a pre-xp look, use Gnome2 or lubuntu with the themes from Gnomelook. I also know a very nice program for Backtrack called [LookLikeXP](http://www.phillips321.co.uk/2012/08/28/making-backtrack5-look-like-xp/), which is amazing.

Generally, I'd suggest looking around at [Gnomelook](http://www.gnome-look.org/) and [KdeLook](http://kde-look.org/) for wonderful themes and stuff.

Comment: @Derfder I might add that you don't need a Windoze look to have a 'sane' desktop, Mint is very nice, and Lubuntu and Xubuntu and, of course Kubuntu as default.